# What is the reporitory name when add docker task in Bamboo?

Tags: docker, bamboo

I am going to publish my web application fresh code to a Linux server tcp://ip_address:2375. The host and container ports both are 8080.

By [this](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2015/09/bamboo-docker-building-web-apps/), what is the repository when adding the docker task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial refers to the repository [`addteq/bamboo-docker-example`](https://bitbucket.org/addteq/bamboo-docker-example) (that you can fork in order to use your own)

It is basically any repo with a Dockerfile able to install your web app.
So you need to create a git repo with your own Dockerfile and resources in order to select said repo in your Bamboo job configuration.